# Overflow doesnt work in <aside>-tag, but in <div> why?

Tags: html, mobile, overflow, mobile-website

I just spend a fair bit of time debugging my mobile application. I'm building a mobile website and implementing an inbox-like UI for one of my views.

As in a lot of mobile applications, I created a side-menu which is revealed at the push of a button. Markup looks like this:

```
<div class="content>
    //Content goes here, inbox items and such
</div>
<aside class="side-menu">
   //Side menu content goes here
</aside>
```

On mobile, the side menu content was overflowing, but the side-menu was not scrollable until i changed the aside-tag to a div-tag.

What creates this behaviour?